# Can the US House and Senate make allowance for self-quarantined members to vote remotely?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate-rules, house-rules

Can the US House and Senate make allowance for self-quarantined members to vote remotely?

Is the requirement that a member be in chamber in the constitution or law - or is it part of the senate or house's rules which they could amend for this specific crisis?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is not explicit rule one way or the other - just tradition and the assumption about what words like "quorum" and "absent" mean.

Constitutionally, this falls under the *"Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings"* catchall. It does require a "quorum" to do business, and "absent" members can be compelled to attend, both of which imply physical presence, but both of which can theoretically be satisfied via telepresence as well.

The House has [rule III(1)](https://rules.house.gov/sites/democrats.rules.house.gov/files/documents/116-House-Rules-Clerk.pdf), which says

> Every Member shall be present
>   within the Hall of the House during its
>   sittings, unless excused or necessarily
>   prevented, and shall vote on each question put, unless having a direct personal or pecuniary interest in the
>   event of such question.

A resolution [has been introduced](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-resolution/890/text?r=2&s=2) to change this requirement, although at least a quorum of Representatives would have to gather in person in order to pass it.

As far as I can tell, the [Senate rules](https://www.rules.senate.gov/rules-of-the-senate) don't address physical presence at all, although they presumably use the standard, in-person, definition of "quorum".

[This Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/2020/03/10/coronavirus-congress-quorum/) gets into it a little deeper (before veering off into opinion), including precedents for changing the definition of quorum.